# R not recognizing scientific notation of imported table?

Tags: r, types, notation

I have a column in a dataframe (read in from a .csv) that has some values in scientific notation and some that are not. Like so:

```
v1 <- c(207669000, 1.48E+08, 8.40E+08, 7.95E+08, 95600000, 1.87E+08)
```

when I call `typeof()` on this column it returns:

```
typeof(v1)
[1] "integer"
```

when I try to convert the type to numeric I get this:

```
 as.numeric(v1)
 [1] 27 15 47 44 62 22
```

Which makes no sense to me. What's going on here? I just want all the values to be in non-scientific notation and also the be the right numbers. I also tried `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: I don't find issue converting like you did `> v1 <- c(207669000, 1.48E+08, 8.40E+08, 7.95E+08, 95600000, 1.87E+08)
> as.numeric(v1)
[1] 207669000 148000000 840000000 795000000  95600000 187000000`

Comment: Scientific notation can represent large integers thus the `typeof(v1)` is correct.  Most likely your problem is the read.csv is reading the v1 column as factors. To convert factors to numeric you need `as.numeric(as.character(…))`

Comment: What is `class(v1)`? I'm guess it's a factor. Are you sure you read the data in correctly? I don't think the sample you provided likely matches your real situation.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed a factor. I didn't know there was a difference between typeof() and class(). That was a frustrating few minutes.